# Recover date and time when a document was saved

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to recover the date and times when a word document was saved? For example, I have a word document that I have been working on for a few days now and I would like to know at what times of the day I have saved the document. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/view-the-version-history-of-an-item-or-file-in-a-list-or-library-HA101853104.aspx#_Toc283617663) for an explanation.

Comment: IF version control was turned on at the point the document was created... or added during the course of the document

Comment: So, if it was not turned on this is not possible?